# Auto Upgrade for Java EE enterprise applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Our current process for upgrading the application is to undeploy the current version, and then deploy the newly created EAR process. 
I have seen softwares which have an "auto update" functionality (such as Spring Tools Suite). The software downloads the updated files automatically and performs a self upgrade. There is no need to download the complete setup again and uninstall/install the application.

I just wanted to check if anything similar exists for Java EE web applications as well?

Comment: This heavily depends on the application server you use.

Comment: @Tichodroma: Right now we are using JBoss 4.x/5 for deployments, but I will want the solution to work on any app server(if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many servers today support hot-deployment, where you deploy the app over the running one.
This of course still needs the functionality to pull the app from somewhere.

In JBoss 4 at least (and I think it is also available in 5), you can tell the deployment scanner to watch multiple directories, so it could monitor e.g. a shared drive and when you put the application there it would see it and pick it up.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! By the way, is it OK to keep the deployment scanner running on a production system? (from performance/security perspective)

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to redeploy code at runtime is to use OSGi. This is a system created to allow automatic dependency resolution. It allows e.g. for you to keep running older code for existing connections, while using the new code for new connections.

It also allows you to link to newer versions of libraries, which are loaded automatically.

See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Helloworld+OSGi+quickstart for a nice quickstart for using OSGi with JBoss 7.

Comment: "The proper way" is controversial :)